# pandasでcsvファイルを読み込むとinvalid character in identifier

Tags: python, pandas, csv

resasからダウンロードした人口データcsvファイルをpandasに読み込みたいが、
以下のエラーメッセージが発生した。

```py
df File "<ipython-input-13-5abd90abec15>", line 4
    df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding="SHIFT-JIS")
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

初歩的なミスと考えて、「”　’　、　.　」の入力違いなど試した。

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/e/view?usp=sharing'
df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding="SHIFT-JIS")　

# dfを表示する
```

Answer (score 1):

`df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding="SHIFT-JIS")`の後ろに全角空白が付いているように見えます。
ソースからコピペしてきたのなら、おそらくそれが原因でしょう。全角空白を削除してみてください。

---

その次のコメントされた問題はおそらくこの記事の関連かと思われます。
[pandasにexcel出力のcsvを読ませる時に注意する点](https://qiita.com/recomemos/items/1032199c5c47f1ce5417)

> これは、test2.csvに、
> ・ハシゴダカ "髙"
> ・タチサキ "﨑"
> 等の、windows拡張文字列が混ざっている事に起因します。
> このような文字を読むためには、文字コードをcp932としてやる必要があります。
>
> ```
> encoding='cp932'
> ```

`encoding='cp932'`を試してみてください。

Comment: 全角空白ありました。削除してみましたが、UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 313: illegal multibyte sequenceのエラーが発生しました。